# Cannot upgrade ipython from 1.1 to 4.0 on Windows 64bit

Tags: pip, ipython

I cannot get my ipython upgraded or installed properly

```
C:\big data\ipython-notebooks>pip install --upgrade ipython
Downloading/unpacking ipython from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/i/ipython/ipython-4.0.0b1.tar.gz#md
5=e32e4ea0ed8312311bb8cb3e0af0bea1
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ipython
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:284: UserWarning: The version specified requires normaliz
ation, consider using '4.0.0b1' instead of '4.0.0-b1'.
      self.metadata.version,

Downloading/unpacking decorator from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/decorator/decorator-4.0.2.tar.g
z#md5=033c9563af492c4ce2680ee6ca481fa7 (from ipython)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package decorator

Downloading/unpacking pickleshare (from ipython)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pickleshare

Downloading/unpacking simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython) (from versions: 0.5
, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8.1, 0.8)
No distributions matching the version for simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython)
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Oskar\pip\pip.log
```

It says I need simplegeneric, but I already have it installed

This is my pip freeze log:

```
C:\big data\ipython-notebooks>pip freeze
(...)
ipython==1.1.0
(...)
pyzmq==14.7.0
(...)
simplegeneric==0.8.1
(...)
```

I'm using Python 2.7 and I have MS VC++ for Python installed

```
C:\big data\ipython-notebooks>python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

**Update**

Specifying version don't work, same with -U flag or without

```
C:\big data\ipython-notebooks>pip install ipython==3.2.1
Downloading/unpacking ipython==3.2.1
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ipython
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:284: UserWarning: The version specified requires normaliz
ation, consider using '4.0.0b1' instead of '4.0.0-b1'.
      self.metadata.version,

  Requested ipython==3.2.1, but installing version 4.0.0b1
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): decorator in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from ipy
thon==3.2.1)
Downloading/unpacking pickleshare (from ipython==3.2.1)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pickleshare

Downloading/unpacking simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython==3.2.1)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython==3.2.1) (from versio
ns: 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8.1, 0.8)
No distributions matching the version for simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython==3.2.1)
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Oskar\pip\pip.log
```

**Update 2**

Pip version is 1.3.1

```
C:\big data\ipython-notebooks>pip --version
pip 1.3.1 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Comment: Can you add `pip --version` and `which pip`?

Comment: @cel I added pip version. Is 1.3 an old one ?. I never had problems with pip neither easy_install till now, and I'm already using it for like 2 years or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update of **pip** to **newer version** (from 1.3.1 to 7.1) helped

```
C:\big data\ipython-notebooks>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-7.1.0.tar.gz#md5=d935ee914607
4b1d3f26c5f0acfd120e
  Downloading pip-7.1.0.tar.gz (1.0MB): 1.0MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pip

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.mailmap'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'pip\_vendor\Makefile'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'contrib'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tasks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests'
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 1.3.1
    Uninstalling pip:
      Successfully uninstalled pip
  Running setup.py install for pip

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.mailmap'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'pip\_vendor\Makefile'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'contrib'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tasks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests'
    Installing pip-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
    Installing pip.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
    Installing pip2.7-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
    Installing pip2.7.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
    Installing pip2-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
    Installing pip2.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...

C:\big data\ipython-notebooks>pip --version
pip 7.1.0 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)

C:\big data\ipython-notebooks>pip install -U ipython==3.2.1
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning:
A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may ca
use certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/secur
ity.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting ipython==3.2.1
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning:
A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may ca
use certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/secur
ity.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading ipython-3.2.1-py2-none-any.whl (3.4MB)
    100% |################################| 3.4MB 82kB/s
Installing collected packages: ipython
  Found existing installation: ipython 1.1.0
    Uninstalling ipython-1.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled ipython-1.1.0
Successfully installed ipython-3.2.1
```